# PaySimple Payment Gateway Api integration in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Can we implement Paysimple gateway api integration in ruby on rails ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unless you want a simple yes/no answer you're going to have to ask a more detailed question. As is you've asked a broad question which is off-topic. What have you tried? What happened when you tried?

Comment: I am require 'paysimple-ruby' and then run Paysimple.api_user = 'APIUSER ' and Paysimple.api_key = "api-key" and then try to create user via  running customer = Paysimple::Customer.create({ first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe' })
 command and i am getting this error which is given below:

NameError: undefined local variable or method `error' for Paysimple:Module

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the links and "[mcve]". We need the information *in the question itself*. Putting it in comments forces potential helpers to read every comment just to make sense of the question. Edit the question, add the information where you would have if you'd included that initially. And, don't use "Edit" or "Updated" tags in the body; We can tell when and where things have been edited because SO keeps track of that stuff.